# Laravel - Argument 2 passed to Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\JsonResponse

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-8

I want to return the data in `$users` as an array  as well as the data in `$this->guard()->user()` as not inside an array. I've tried as giveb below. But it generates the error - `Argument 2 passed to Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\JsonResponse::__construct() must be of the type int, object given, called in C:\\wamp64\\www\\Laravel\\projects\\Content-Que-Laravel-API\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\JsonResponse.php on line 32`. Am using Laravel-8 & pgsql -13.
How to solve this? Any suggestions..

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
            ->get();
return response()->json(['data' => $users],$this->guard()->user());
```

Expected output:

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "mrt",
    "email": "ba@f.com",
    "phone": 1112223333,
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "OTP": null,
    "ph_OTP": 6033,
    "email_OTP": 1090,
    "user_access_token": null,
    "created_at": "2021-07-20T06:49:29.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-07-20T06:49:29.000000Z"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"as not inside an array"_? Can you please show us an example of the expected response? Showing is way more efficient than a vague explanation. Either way, the second argument to that function needs to be an integer (it seems to be where you can set the HTTP status for the response). All data you want to return as json must be in the first argument.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson see the updated question. I've added sample output

Comment: What parts of that output comes from `$users` and what parts comes from `$this->guard()->user()`? Where is `data`? Please show us an example of the _full_ response (the format). This seems to be just a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass like below result, because second arugment in jsonresponse is http status(200, 401).

```
return response()->json([
    'data' => [
        'users' => $users, 
        'guard' => $this->guard()->user()
    ]
]);
```